# Adding item to array once when function is called multiple times?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, callback, delegates

I want to add a channel to an array of channels if its level is above a threshold, this function is the delegate callback for providing the channel level.

This fucn is used constantly to provide level data, however On init i want to add the channels above the threshold to an array. However then i dont want it to add them again, just 1 instance of each channel that meets the criteria.

I wanted to use this code and check if the channel i receive data from is already in the channelArray, if it isnt, then add it and if it is then skip over it...However its not calling / working.

Can anyone help me with the approach to this? Issue is each channel calls this func every time its moved, so i need it to just run the code to add to array a single time.

```
- (void)cdcControlDidReceiveBusSend:(NSInteger)channel withValue:(float)value forBus:(NSInteger)bus onModule:(NSInteger)module {
    NSNumber *recievingChannel = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:channel];
    NSLog(@"RECIEVED SEND DATA FOR CHAN:%ld VALUE:%f FORBUS:%ld", (long)channel, value, (long)bus);
    if (value != -80.000000) {
        NSLog(@"CHANNEL:%ld FADER IS UP ATTEMPTING TO ADD TO FOCUS ARRAY", (long)channel);

        for (NSNumber *arrayChannel in self.focusChannels) {
            if (recievingChannel == arrayChannel) {
                NSLog(@"ALREADY SAVED THIS CHANNEL...SKIPPING");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"ADDING CHANNEL %ld", (long)channel);
                [self.focusChannels addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:channel]]; // add the channel number to the array of channel numbers if the fader is up
                NSLog(@"FOCUS ARRAY NOW CONTAINS %lu CHANNELS", (unsigned long)self.focusChannels.count);
            }
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"CHANNEL:%ld FADER IS DOWN NOT IN MIXFOCUS ARRAY", (long)channel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you compare the arrayChannel's integer value to `channel` rather than creating a receivingChannel immediately?

Comment: how do you mean? just use channel rather than creating a local instance? how would that make a difference?

Comment: It makes the difference that @Toma points out in the accepted answer.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `==` operator to compare values of `NSNumber`. In order to do things right you ned to use comparator method, like `isEqueal`

```
if ([recievingChannel isEqual:arrayChannel]) {
    //...
}
```

or compare values directly

```
if (recievingChannel.integerValue == arrayChannel.integerValue){
    //...
}
```

Anyway, this task can be solved using [-[NSArray containsObject:]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1407477-containsobject)

```
- (void)cdcControlDidReceiveBusSend:(NSInteger)channel withValue:(float)value forBus:(NSInteger)bus onModule:(NSInteger)module {
    if (value != -80.000000) {
        if ([self.focusChannels containsObject:@(channel)] == NO) {
            [self.focusChannels addObject:@(channel)];
        }
    }
}
```